# bool(false) can't mysql_fetch_array = null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have problems why this give me bool(false)
i can't get any id from mysql_fetch_array = null

```
$doVariable = isset($_GET['task']) ? $_GET['task'] : null;
require_once('connect-server.php');
$account = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from baza.account where id = '".$account['id']."' limit 1"));

var_dump($account);
var_dump($_SESSION);
session_start();
```

anyone know why this doesn't work?
$_SESSION working fine
var_dump($_SESSION);

```
bool(false) array(1) { ["logged"]=> string(2) "16" }
```

16 is id of account

with PDO

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name, poziom FROM postac WHERE id = :id');
$statement->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
foreach($statement as $row)
{
    echo($row['name']." ".$row['poziom']."<br />");
}
$statement->closeCursor();

var_dump($pdo);
```

object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: Are you getting anything from the database? I mean, the problem is for this query in specific?

Comment: yes i can't get from database any values

Comment: Why is PDO tagged? Are you using PDO somewhere? Don't just `fetch` your `query` result, see if the query worked first.

Comment: yes i have pdo on login.php

Comment: If you use PDO why are you using `mysql_*`? Use PDO everywhere, just delete this code and use the correct driver.

Comment: @chris85 PDO too doesn't work ;]

Comment: Please update and show that usage.

Comment: @chris85 done error object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: Whats the error information from `$statement`?

Comment: @chris85 object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(46) "SELECT name, poziom FROM postac WHERE id = :id" }

Comment: `print_r($pdo->errorInfo());` is `0`?